# PHP SoapClient always returns NULL reponse even if I get a valid XML debug

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've been trying to get data from a SOAP service using PHP SoapClient.
If I point to http://my-service?WSDL (obviously I can't expose the correct one) away from PHP on a well know tool called SOAP UI with the right parameters I get a proper response. But In PHP I always get NULL in my response even with the right params and stuff.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient('http://my-service?WSDL', 
                             array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>true));
    $params= ['EBMHeader'=> ['EBMID'=> 'anyvalue'], 
              'DataArea'=> ['Ip'=> '127.0.0.1', 'RequestId'=> '12345']];
try {
    $response= $client->MySoapFunction($params);
    var_dump($response);    // returns always NULL
    echo $client->__getLastResponse(); //Returns a valid XML with the proper data

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo $exception;
}
```

I already tried these:

- Double checked the wsdl and parameters
- Changed soap options: trace and exceptions
- Changed params keys to see if it fails, it does and SOAP server responds  that the param is misssing or whatever the error is, for instance I can say that I'm getting a response from SOAP server.
- Tried to debug using __getLastResponse(), it shows a valid XML with the expected data, also I validated the XML to see if it's ok.
- Tried to use `$client->__soapCall('MySoapFunction', $params, null);`
  and the result is the same.
- I also tried to use the `__getLastResponse()` output and parse it to var so them i could convert it to an array but the result is an empty object:

`$xml= $client->__getLastResponse();
$response = simplexml_load_string($xml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);`

This is my XML request from PHP with `$client->__getLastRequest()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/" xmlns:ns2="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Autogestion/Producto/ABM/V1/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:ConsultarProductoABM>
            <ns1:EBMHeader>
                <ns1:EBMID>whatever</ns1:EBMID>
            </ns1:EBMHeader>
            <ns2:DataArea>
                <ns2:Ip>127.0.0.1</ns2:Ip>
                <ns2:RequestId>12345</ns2:RequestId>
            </ns2:DataArea>
        </ns2:ConsultarProductoABM>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is my response `$client->__getLastResponse()`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Body xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <v1:ConsultarProductoResponseEBM xmlns:v1="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBM/Producto/V1/">
            <v11:EBMHeader xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/">
                <v11:EBMID>anything</v11:EBMID>
                <v11:CreationDateTime>2015-10-16T19:09:54.962-03:00</v11:CreationDateTime>
                <v11:Sender>ATG</v11:Sender>
                <v11:Target>SMFLX</v11:Target>
                <v11:BusinessScope>SIN_CONFIGURACION</v11:BusinessScope>
                <v11:BusinessScope>SIN_CONFIGURACION</v11:BusinessScope>
                <v11:BusinessScope>SIN_CONFIGURACION</v11:BusinessScope>
                <v11:BusinessScope>e6e00a83-ce05-4e2a-bdb6-d7bfbd14d84a</v11:BusinessScope>
                <v11:EBMTracking>ConsultarProductoAutogestionReqABCS (V1).ConsultarProducto_+++_ConsultarProductoProvisioningProvABCS (V1).ConsultarProducto_+++_ValidarRespuestaEBS (V1).ValidarRespuesta_+++_ConsultarProductoOpenSmartFlexProvABCS (V1).ConsultarProducto_+++_ValidarRespuestaEBS (V1).ValidarRespuesta</v11:EBMTracking>
                <v11:FaultNotification>
                    <ns1:FaultMessage xmlns:ns2="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Autogestion/Producto/ABM/V1/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                    <ns1:FaultingService xmlns:ns2="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Autogestion/Producto/ABM/V1/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                    <ns1:Destination xmlns:ns2="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Autogestion/Producto/ABM/V1/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
                </v11:FaultNotification>
            </v11:EBMHeader>
            <v11:ReturnCode xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/">0</v11:ReturnCode>
            <v11:ReturnMessage xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/"/>
            <v11:ErrorCode xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Common/EBM/Ebm/V1/">0</v11:ErrorCode>
            <v1:DataArea>
                <v1:InstalledProduct>
                    <v11:Hub xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/InstalledProduct/V1/">BON</v11:Hub>
                    <v11:Node xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/InstalledProduct/V1/">BON076A</v11:Node>
                    <v11:CustomerParty xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/InstalledProduct/V1/">
                        <v12:Id xmlns:v12="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/CustomerParty/V1/">7889679</v12:Id>
                        <v12:PartyHuman xmlns:v12="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/CustomerParty/V1/">
                            <v13:FirstName xmlns:v13="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/Common/V1/">JOHN</v13:FirstName>
                            <v13:LastName xmlns:v13="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/Common/V1/">DOE</v13:LastName>
                        </v12:PartyHuman>
                        <v12:Location xmlns:v12="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/CustomerParty/V1/">
                            <v13:Address xmlns:v13="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/Common/V1/">
                                <v13:ProvinceName>LACATION</v13:ProvinceName>
                                <v13:StateName>LACATION</v13:StateName>
                                <v13:CityName>LACATION</v13:CityName>
                            </v13:Address>
                        </v12:Location>
                    </v11:CustomerParty>
                    <v11:ContractID xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/InstalledProduct/V1/">123456</v11:ContractID>
                    <v11:Service xmlns:v11="http://url.com/EnterpriseObjects/Core/EBO/InstalledProduct/V1/">
                        <v11:ClassId>52</v11:ClassId>
                    </v11:Service>
                </v1:InstalledProduct>
            </v1:DataArea>
        </v1:ConsultarProductoResponseEBM>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The problem is that i don't know what else to do to get a valid php response if i do:

```
$response= $client->MySoapFunction($params);
 var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I was having a simliar issue but using `$client->__soapCall('MySoapFunction', $params, null);` instead of the actual method called resulted in the `stdClass` being returned with the correct data :)